# Transformation flickers in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a transformation for my banner element which resizes the image a little on scrolling, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/5gLdfjfm/1/)

The code for the transformation is as follows:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var x = $(this).scrollTop(),
        transY = (x * 0.5), scale = 1 + (x * 0.0003),
        transform = 'translateY('+transY+'px) scale('+scale+') translate3d(0,0,0)';
    $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner').css({
      opacity: 1 - (x * 0.0008),
      WebkitTransform: transform,
      MozTransform: transform,
      msTransform: transform,
      transform: transform
    });
  });
```

My problem is, whilst the animation runs perfectly smooth in firefox, I get a flickering / visible resizing effect in chrome.

Is there anything I should change in the css to get it running smoothly in chrome, or is this browser just not capable to do an easy transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a basic test with setTimeout :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var x = $(this).scrollTop(),
        transY = (x * 0.5), scale = 1 + (x * 0.0003),
        transform = 'translateY('+transY+'px) scale('+scale+') translate3d(0,0,0)';


    setTimeout(function(){

        $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner').css({
          opacity: 1 - (x * 0.0008),
          WebkitTransform: transform,
          MozTransform: transform,
          msTransform: transform,
          transform: transform
        });

    }, 3);


}); // - EOF - $(window).scroll(function()
```

Comment: It looks like you would like to do a CSS animation from a start state to and end state. Maybe incrementing like you do now, instead of relying on CSS for animation description, is overkill. Did you try to record a Timeline in Chrome Dev Tools ? Do you see spikes all over the place (over the 30fps bar) ?

Comment: Yeah, way over 30fps. The setTimeout unfortunately made it even a little worse... Do you think it'll be better/possible with pure css?

Comment: I have no performance issue whatsoever in Chrome 39 Mac OS X, everything is smooth and well under 60fps - Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36

Comment: Yeah, the fiddle is quite nice for me to. My pictures might be a little to large for the animation, not really sure..

Comment: In the real world case, does the image comes from server side? Is it heavy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66353/discussion-between-bonatoc-and-baao).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it more like this:

```
var x, transY, transform, scale, c = $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner');
$(window)
    .scroll(function() {
        x = $(this)
            .scrollTop();
        transY = (x * 0.5);
        scale = 1 + (x * 0.0003);
        transform = 'translateY(' + transY + 'px) scale(' + scale + ') translate3d(0,0,0)';
    });
requestAnimationFrame(function anim() {
    c.css({
        opacity: 1 - (x * 0.0008),
        WebkitTransform: transform,
        MozTransform: transform,
        msTransform: transform,
        transform: transform
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
});
```

But I never saw the flickering you are talking about in chrome.

Comment: I do not see such a difference in my personal experience with setTimeout. But nonetheless, this should be the standard practice as it takes more accurately account of the browser and GPU capabilites of the user's machine.